# How to convert Kivymd file to APk file

Tags: python, kivymd

I am new to Kivymd. I have managed to create a testing mobile app with the help of online resources. However, when attempting to convert the main.py file to an APK file using Google Colab notebook, I encountered an error and was unable to generate the mobile app APK file.

What is the correct process for converting the Kivymd main.py file to an APK file?

Comment: Instead all the fluff in your question, please include actual details. What are you trying to convert, and what happened.